# I can't wrap my head around Peano's 5'th axiom

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm currently reading about Peano's axiom and the construction of the natural numbers. The fifth Axiom of Peano does not make sense to me:

- If a subset $T$ contains $0$ as an element and for all $n \in T$, $s(n)$ is also in $T$, then $T$ is the set of Natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$.

I know that this axiom exists in order to exclude elements which could have the following property:
$$s(a) = b$$ $$s(b) = a$$

These elements would not violate axioms $1$ to $4$ however they don't have the desired "natural number" properties hence axiom $5$ has been created to allegedly clean these elements up. I also know that axiom $5$ is supposed to work as follows:

- If $0$ is in our set $T$ then $s(0)$ is also in $T$ but if $s(0)$ is in $T$ then $s(s(0))$ is also in $T$ and so on. Thus we declare this set to be the natural numbers.

Now to my actual question: suppose we throw in $a$ and $b$ and $0$ into $T$. Since we do not yet know what the natural numbers are, we can't exclude $a,b$ either (if my thinking is correct). Then for all $n$ in $T$ the succesor $s(n)$ is also in $T$. As previously stated $s(0), s(s(0)), ...$ are all in in $T$ (the actual natural numbers) but if such elements $a$ and $b$ are also in T then their successor $s(a)$ and $s(b)$ are also in $T$ which is  a true statement since $s(a) = b$ and $s(b) =a$.

Axiom $5$ should exclude such elements but the way I am stating it, it seems like these elements do not violate axiom $5$.

Comment: The fifth axiom, as usually stated, does not say that $T=\Bbb N$: it says that $T\supseteq\Bbb N$. The presence of $a$ and $b$ in $T$ is then not a problem.

Comment: The line "Since we do not yet know what the natural numbers are" suggests to me that you're thinking of the PA axioms as *building* the natural numbers. Think of them instead as *describing* the natural numbers: $\mathbb{N}$ is "over there," and we're writing down some basic facts about it which will help us understand it better. Note, then, that the "subset" bit of the axiom rules out non-natural numbers from consideration.

Comment: What does "and so on" really mean? We cannot $define$ $\Bbb N$ as $\{s^n(0): n\in \Bbb N\}$ because this is circular: The term $\Bbb N$ in the expression $\{s^n(0): n\in\Bbb N\}$ cannot be used before it is defined.

Comment: @NoahSchweber you write "Think of them instead as describing the natural numbers..." Is that why there is no axiom that says "the successor of a natural number n is n + 1" (as opposed to n + 0.5) ? I always felt that the Peano axioms do not explicitly state that the successor function is "+1", as if that is a given.

Comment: Can you cite the source of the first quote? Where did you get it from? I wonder if it should read “ If a subset T [of $\mathbb{N}$]contains 0 as an element and for all n∈T, s(n) is also in T, then T is the set of Natural numbers N.”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Axiom 5, in conjunction with the other four axioms, tells you that:

1. Every natural number other than $0$ is a successor; and
2. You can “reach” every natural number by starting with $0$ and applying the successor function finitely many times.

To see that the five axioms prevent you from having “cycles” with the successor function, note first that we cannot have $s(a)=a$ for any $a$. To see this, consider
$$T = \{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid n\neq S(n)\}.$$
By Peano’s third axiom, $0\in T$ (since $0$ is not a successor, so $0\neq S(0))$.

Assume $k\in T$. Then $k\neq S(k)$. By Peano’s fourth axioms, this implies $S(k)\neq S(S(k))$; hence $S(k)\in T$.

By Peano’s Fifth Axiom, $T=\mathbb{N}$.  In particular, $S(a)\neq a$ for all $a\in\mathbb{N}$.

Similarly, if $S(a)=b$ and $S(b)=a$, then $S(S(a))=a$. Consider
$$T=\{a\in\mathbb{N}\mid a\neq S(S(a))\}.$$
Again, $0\in T$, since $0$ is not a successor. Assume $k\in T$. Then $k\neq S(S(k))$, hence $S(k)\neq S(S(S(k))$, so $S(k)\in T$. Thus, $T=\mathbb{N}$, and you cannot have the two elements you propose.

You can similarly verify that there cannot exist elements $a_1,\ldots,a_m$ with $S(a_i) = a_{i+1}$ for $i=1,\ldots,m-1$, and $S(a_m)=a_1$.

Comment: Does there have to be a separate proof for each $m$ or is there a proof for all $m$. Probably need a proof by induction on $m$.

Comment: @martycohen: If you first prove that every number is either $0$ or a successor (which requires induction), then you can use the well-ordering principle (which is essentially induction): if there exist $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k\gt 0$ such that $S^k(m)=m$, let $m_0$ be the least such natural number, and let $k_0$ be the least positive integer such that $S^{k_0}(m_0)=m_0$. Then $m_0\neq 0$ because $0$ is not a successor. Then $m_0=S(r)$ for some $r$; therefore $r\neq S^{k_0}(r)$, and so $m=S(r)\neq S(S^{k_0}(r)) = S^{k_0}(S(r))) = S^{k_0}(m)$, which is impossible. Thus, no such $m$ and $k$ exist.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin If we don't apply the Axiom of Induction (AI), then the set $\mathbb{N}$ satisfying the rest of the Peano axioms can contain a member $a$ such that $S(a) = a$. (AI) is supposed to exclude $a$ from $\mathbb{N}$. I don't think it does. Your proof, which I have found in Elliott's book, for the nonexistence of such $a$ in $P$ cleverly picks a set $T$ where there is no such member as $a$. Then it shows that, $T$ satisfies the conditions of (AI). Thus applying (AI), you have $T = \mathbb{N}$, proving $\mathbb{N}$ can't have such $a$.

[Continued in the next comment.]

Comment: But I could choose the set $T = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : n \neq S(n)\} \cup \{a\}$, which the OP tried to demonstrate. This set $T$ also satisfies the conditions of (AI). Thus applying (AI), we have $T = \mathbb{N}$, proving $\mathbb{N}$ doesn't contain such $a$. So, the Axiom of Induction doesn't exclude such "rogue" members from $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @MostafizurRahman:  You cannot apply AI to $T$ unless you first establish that $T\subset\mathbb{N}$. You have not, since that would require you to assume that $a\in\mathbb{N}$, which would make your argument circular: if you assume $\mathbb{N}$ contains "rogue" elements, then you can conclude that $\mathbb{N}$ has "rogue" elements. Big whoop. That does not establish the existence, or even the possible existence, of such elements; it just shows that if you assume your conclusion, you get your conclusion. My argument, on the other hand, has no such assumption. So, you are just wrong.

Comment: @MostafizurRahman: Remember, the Axiom of Induction says: "If $T$ is a **subset of $\mathbb{N}$** such that $0\in T$ and for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n\in T$ implies $s(n)\in T$, then $T=\mathbb{N}$." You cannot invoke it for random sets, only for subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Aa.... that's some nasty trick! Thank you for clarifying it. I'm learning these axioms for the first time. This helps a lot.

Comment: @MostafizurRahman It's not a "trick", it's what the Axiom of Induction says.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes. I understand. I was referring to the wit of the person who came up with the axiom.

Answer (score 0):

(Posted after previous posting was accepted.)

> I know that this axiom exists in order to exclude elements which could
> have the following property:
>
> $~~~~s(a) = b$
>
> $~~~~s(b) = a$

$\cdots$

> Axiom $5$ should exclude such elements but the way I am stating it, it
> seems like these elements do not violate axiom $5$.

In this case, $a, b\neq 0$ and $\{a, b\}$ is an isolated, closed loop under the successor function $s$, i.e. neither of the elements of  $\{a, b\}$ are accessible from any other natural numbers. This contradicts the fact that induction holds on $N$.

It can be shown that induction holds on any set $X$ with $x_0$ being the "first" element under the successor function $f$ if and only if there exists no such isolated (unconnected?) subsets $Y\subset X$ under $f$, with $x_0 \notin Y$. (See my formal proof using a form of natural deduction [here](http://www.dcproof.com/InductionIffAccessible.htm), 228 lines) .