# Is a set $T$ containing all natural numbers identical to $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: peano-axioms

[In this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4784841/peano-s-fifth-axiom-as-stated-by-russell?noredirect=1#comment10174362_4785468), I see that Mauro Allegranza and I were saying the same thing as shown in the table below:

| Allegranza | Zeynel |
| --- | --- |
| $0 \in T$ | $0 \in T$ |
| $n \in T$ | $n \in T$ |
| $S(n) \in T$ | $S(n) \in T$ |
| $ T = \mathbb{N}$ | $T$ contains all natural numbers |

Allegranza claims my version is not correct. But to me "$ T = \mathbb{N}$" and "$T$ contains all natural numbers" are identical statements. Is there a difference I don't understand?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ contains all natural numbers but $\mathbb{R} \neq \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis's example was the one that came to my mind when I started to think of examples where the larger set had cardinality greater than $\aleph_0$.

Answer (score 2):

> But to me "$T=\Bbb{N}$" and "$T$ contains all natural numbers" are identical statements.

$T=\Bbb{N}$ means that $T\subseteq\Bbb{N}$ and $\Bbb{N}\subseteq T$. On the other hand, the statement "$T$ contains all natural numbers" only means that $\Bbb{N}\subseteq T$.

Therefore, "$T=\Bbb{N}$" and "$T$ contains all natural numbers" are different statements.

Comment: I would use $\subseteq$ rather than $\subset$ here, because the latter one usually means a proper subset

Comment: Thank you for your comment.